# How to fix xdg-open: no method available for opening 'http://localhost:80'

Tags: linux, xampp, xdgutils

When I press the button [Go To Application] in the XAMPP 7.3.6
Shows me this:

```
xdg-open: no method available for opening 'http://localhost:80'
```

I set the `/usr/bin/xdg-open` where `google-chromium` is now `chromium`. That solved all my problems and bugs but now shows me this new problem and no other question among here solved my question.

When I run `./xampp*`, I get this:

```
xdg-open: no method available for opening 'http://localhost:80'
```

Answer (score 3):

The XDG (X development group) has a **xdg-utils** toolset that are used to open manuals files (e.g., html). You can use lynx in your terminal to open the default web-page at `http://localhost:80`

```
sudo apt-get install lynx
```

and press **Go To Application** in XAMPP.

**

### Why this usually doesn't open in GUI web-browser?

**

This is because GUI browser are usually configured not to run as root (sudo) user because of security reasons. And although in xdg-settings, it is configured to open in default-web-browser, it's still not gonna open because of browsers are not configured to run via root.

You can check xdg-settings as `sudo xdg-settings --list`
And, you can change xdg-settings config. by editing `sudo nano /usr/bin/xdg-settings`
[image]

So, if you want to open your localhost in web-browser then configure web-browser to open as root (sudo) and change xdg-settings accordingly.

As you can see below, I ran wireshark as sudo and opened dumppcap manual (html page) in lynx console based browser. 
[image]